# How to pass shell string to c program with EOF?

Tags: c, linux, shell

Bit of a C noob and especially shell noob, so excuse me for that. I have an assignment where I have to read a string from a shell script and input it into a c program with stdin. The prof is giving us an already written script, and the strings start with << EOF and end with EOF. I have no idea how to process this string in my program. Thanks for the help.

The c program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
  int i = 0, aCount = 0, eCount = 0, iCount = 0, oCount = 0, uCount = 0;
  while(argv[1][i] != EOF){
    if(argv[1][i] == 'A' || argv[1][i] == 'a'){
      aCount++;
    }
    if(argv[1][i] == 'E' || argv[1][i] == 'e'){
      eCount++;
    }
    if(argv[1][i] == 'I' || argv[1][i] == 'i'){
      iCount++;
    }
    if(argv[1][i] == 'O' || argv[1][i] == 'o'){
      oCount++;
    }
    if(argv[1][i] == 'U' || argv[1][i] == 'u'){
      uCount++;
    }
    i++;
  }
  printf("%s%d\n", "Number of A's: ", aCount);
  printf("%s%d\n", "Number of E's: ", eCount);
  printf("%s%d\n", "Number of I's: ", iCount);
  printf("%s%d\n", "Number of O's: ", oCount);
  printf("%s%d\n", "Number of U's: ", uCount);
  return 0;
}
```

The script:

```
run () {
  echo "$*"
  if $*
  then echo 'success'
  else echo 'error'
  fi
}

run ./count_vowels <<EOF
Adieu, Bo!
EOF
```

Comment: You're supposed to read input (as if from the keyboard), not access arguments in `argv`

Comment: Do not be confused by the string `EOF`.  In the shell script, you could write it as `run ./count_vowels << FOO` (and replace the terminating "EOF" with "FOO").  There is absolutely no relationship between the "EOF" in the shell script and the pre-processor token EOF in your C code.  The shell script is just passing the string "Adieu, Bo!\n" to your program as data on stdin.  All you have to do is read it (with `getchar` or `fgetc` or the like).

Comment: Note that `while(argv[1][i] != EOF){` will only terminate if `argv[1]` contains a character with code 0xFF and if plain `char` is a signed type (and if EOF is actually defined as `-1`, but that's normally the case — I'm not aware of an exception — even though it isn't formally mandated by the C standard).  Your program should be reading from standard input; the shell handles the I/O redirection for you so that the content of the 'here document' is available as the standard input to your program.  Your program won't see the `<<EOF` notation.

Answer (score 5):

`<<EOF` is a shell notation that means ”Read the following lines from the script until `EOF` is seen and pipe them into the program as its standard input.”

To the program, this will appears as a regular stream in `stdin`. You can read with the usual functions including `getchar`, `scanf`, and so on, until the end-of-file (really end-of-stream) is reached, at which point the functions will indicate they cannot read further in their various ways. (Largely by returning `EOF`, but note that `scanf` may return other values if partial matching occurs in one call before end-of-stream is reached, such as return 0 or 1 to indicate 0 or 1 items were assigned although 2 were requested.)

This is called a [here document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04). See your shell documentation for variations and embellishments. The particular string “EOF” was chosen by your instruction; one could use other things accepted by the shell, such as:

```
ProgramName Arguments <<EndOfMyInput
MyLine1
MyLine2
MyLine3
EndOfMyInput
```

Comment: The notation is called a [here document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) (POSIX) or [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents).  The OP probably doesn't need to get into all the intricacies of multiple here documents starting on the same line that POSIX covers.